# Python Script input via Bash Shell

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

I have a python script which i am calling from bash script and this bash script get call from cron

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
set -o xtrace
echo "Verify/Update Firmware"
/usr/bin/python -u /usr/bin/Update.py
```

Now when this python run it ask for some input(from keyboard), but i am not able to capture it. How my python can get input in this scenario?

Python script look like below

```
ip = raw_input('Enter IP for Switch')
tn = telnetlib.Telnet ( ip, 23, 600 )
```

Answer (score 0):

For giving command line arguments to a bash script you can use $1, $2, $3 etc. The tutorial here talks about this: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0120.php

For the python part you can use something like argparse to do this pretty nicely. This also had loads of tutorials out there.

Comment: in python i suppose to get input from keyboard

Answer (score 0):

For a single line of input use this:

`echo "input" | command arg1 arg2`

For multiple lines write the expected input to a file, then redirect the input:

`command arg1 arg2 < inputfile`

It is not guaranteed to work depending on many details.

Please consider the risk of blindly giving input without reading what the program wants.

For a more sophisticated solution check the `expect` utility.